# Cannot connect to server, error message says “java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused”

Tags: networking, router, java, firewall, port-forwarding

I have been trying to get a minecraft server running for some time now to no avail. I apologize for the fact that this is not as technically advanced a question as is intended for this forum, and that I am not a programmer, but I have been trying to make this server work for months and no amount of my own research or posting on other forums has yet helped. If anyone could help me here, or perhaps direct me to someplace else, I would very much appreciate it.

I'm using the 1.8.7 exe server program, on a windows 8 computer with an ASUS RT-AC66R. My ISP is comcast, and my family recently switched to business class internet for my parents' home business. Oddly, the server worked before this switch.

I have ensured that I have forwarded my port correctly, and tried ports other than Minecraft's default 25565. Even after forwarding a port through my router, port checkers still say that the port is closed. I have tried setting up a static IP, putting my local IP in the router's DMZ, shutting off firewalls and anti-virus programs, and making rules and exceptions in program and port firewalls. Nothing has worked so far.

I have read that the error message I have been receiving is usually either due to firewall problems or because the server is not responding to attempts to connect. It should not be the former, unless there is still some firewall trick I haven't tried. I've read that some ISPs block certain ports, but comcast does claim to block any of the ports I have tried. If it is an issue with the server itself, how do I know?

Again, I am sorry that neither this topic nor myself are completely appropriate for this forum, but I am desperate after trying to make this work for so long.

Comment: Note that for a port to be open, in addition to forwarding ports, there must be a service listening on the port. on the server, confirm that an application has opened that port. in an elevated powershell, run `netstat -abno | findstr 25565`. if you dont get output, check to confirm that the application is running and correctly configured to use 25565. Also confirm that if the application supports interface binding, that it is bound to your LAN IP or to 0.0.0.0, but not to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You've tried a port other than 25565 *at the router*? If not, I wonder if Comcast is purposely blocking it, despite their having denied it. And NEVER underestimate the ability of Windows Firewall to cause hard-to-find headaches.

Comment: Thank you both for replying.  I haven't used powershell before, and had to research it before I could use it.  The cmdlet you gave me said that 0.0.0.0:25565 was listening and that [::]25565 was listening.  Both were TCP, which is strange because in the router the port is forwarded as both TCP and UDP.  I don't know what interface binding is, and couldn't find anything which explained it, but I think I know what you mean.  Could you give me the layman's terms or direct me to where I could learn about it?  The server has a properties folder wherein you can set the server IP; this did not fix.

Comment: By "at the router", do you mean creating a port forwarding rule on the router itself?  If so, yes, I did that.  I'm pretty sure that Comcast doesn't block the port because it worked fine before, and I had Comcast then too.  What could I do to find any problems Windows Firewall might give me?  Or could I simply turn it off and see if that helps?

Comment: ok, that netstat output looks perfect. don't worry about the TCP/UDP. when looking at the host's listening ports, it is the applciation that opened them, so that is all the app believes it needs to do its job, and thats generally good enough for me. you can probably turn off the UDP forward, as UDP forward traffic can sometimes allow a sophisticated attacker illicit access to the network.  So, if you are confident that your port forward rules are correct, then it is likely that there is a software firewall causing issues. review your port forward rules, and your win firewall ruleset.

Comment: for windows firewall, check your event logs -> security logs immediately after attempting to connect to the port. they shoudl show messages about dropped packets.

Comment: I reviewed my firewall rules and the port forward rules.  They all look in order.  I've allowed port 25565 inbound and outbound, as well as minecraft.exe, minecraft_server.1.8.7.exe, minecraft_server.1.8.7.jar, java.exe, and javaw.exe.  All of the tutorials I have seen for setting up a server on minecraft have said to have the port forward rule set to TCP as well as UDP, so I hesitate to change to only TCP.

Comment: I checked the event logs for the firewall, and I did not see anything recent about dropped packets, though I don't think that it is logging that information.  I will try to fix this later today.

Comment: It took awhile to set the firewall to log packet data, and to give myself access to the log, but it is blank.

Comment: I found a setting in my router which logs accepted and dropped packets.  I've turned it on, but now I can't seem to find the log.

Comment: I've had no luck finding it.  Any other ideas?